# SQL query: Get rows where column A not exists with same value and column value B

Tags: sql, oracle

Sorry, for the confusing title, but did not found a better one. Here is the situation:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_id    int  NOT NULL,
    company_id  int  NOT NULL,
    last_update date     NULL
)
```

Table Data:

```
ORDER_ID   COMPANY_ID       LAST_UPDATE  
       1            1        2020/06/08  
       2            1        2020/06/08  
       3            1        2020/06/08  
       4            2        2020/06/08  
       5            2        2020/01/27  
       6            3        2020/06/08  
       7            3        2020/06/08  
       8            3        2020/06/08  
       9            3        NULL  
      10            4        2020/06/08  
      11            4        2020/06/08  
      12            4        2020/06/08  
      13            4        2020/06/08  
      14            4        2020/06/08
```

I want to have all rows, with a company, where there is no row with the same company and a LAST_UPDATE older than 3 months (or null).

#### What does not work:

I cannot use a simple WHERE clause with the date, because this filters me out just the rows 5 and 9. I only want the rows 1-3 & 10-14.

#### What works, but is to slow:

I can use a subquery (AND company_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT company_id [...])), but this completely kills my performance. In prod environment I have nearly 50M rows, the ResultSet of the subquery is too huge.

#### My current workaround:

I just ordered my results by company_id, last_update and use a "continue" in my Java Code, if there is a too old last_update. But that's also not optimal.

#### Question:

Is there are performant SQL only way, to achive this. Maybe over a "group by ... having" - clause.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I can use a subquery (AND company_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT company_id [...])), but this completely kills my performance" - sounds like you're missing an index. What indexes are defined on this table, and what is your current level of index fragmentation? What type of churn (qualitatively) does this table experience?

Comment: Missing index is one issue, but the best tipp was changing from NOT IN to NOT EXISTS in my case. I was not aware of the "SELECT 1" - Syntax. Using this is much better, than using "SELECT DISTINCT company_id", because this can lead to million ids, which makes the NOT IN check very expensive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use window functions:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*, min(last_update) over (partition by company_id) as min_last_update
      from orders o
     ) o
where min_last_update >= add_months(sysdate, -3);
```

But a simple `not exists` should also be fine:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where not exists (select 1
                  from orders o2
                  where o2.company_id = o.company_id and
                        o2.last_update < add_months(sysdate, -3)
                 );
```

Either of these can take advantage of an index on `orders(company_id, last_update)`.

Comment: thx! Switching from "NOT IN" to "NOT EXISTS" gave me a huge performance boost.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WINDOW` functions as follows:

```
SELECT T.* FROM (
    SELECT T.*,
           MIN(CASE WHEN LAST_UPDATE IS NULL THEN LAST_UPDATE - 100 
                    ELSE LAST_UPDATE END) OVER(
               PARTITION BY T.COMPANY_ID
           ) AS MIN_LAST_UPDATE
      FROM ORDERS T ) T
 WHERE T.MIN_LAST_UPDATE >= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, - 3);
```